# Why won't my js form submit work?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

I have an iframe and a form. I want to submit the form into the iframe. This works, but the JS won't submit the form. I want the form to submit on page load or just when the script is rendered by the browser. I have already tried about 10 different JavaScript variants and successfully submitted the form with a button. Any thoughts?

```
<iframe src="http://domain.com" name="i0"></iframe>

<form action="http://domain.com/" target="i0" id="f0" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="secret" value="4cda562cd5dafa1882c9f18dc0dc5dba">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="39">
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('f0').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: what's the `}` at the end after the .submit();?

Comment: Why use a form like this and not just do an XHR POST?

Comment: are you sure there isn't any other `f0` id on the page? I see nothing wrong with the code, I think you just missed something maybe another `id="f0"` or `name="i0"` on the same page

Comment: CodeBird: Just checked, not using it anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<input type="submit" name="submit">`

this is what's causing your issue, change its name to something else. because now this

`document.getElementById('f0').submit();`

is trying to access that input, and giving the error:

`TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function`

You should have posted all your form code here, we could have found it faster :)

Comment: +1 and ya really boring when OP don't post enough info and wait 30 min to post a link (in a comment) pointing to online sample. This could have been fixed in 30 sec...

Comment: Your right, I added that back after posting to debug. Thank You!

Comment: Or, you can keep your submit button and use `document.getElementById('f0').submit.click()`

Answer (score 0):

I see, you cant' use `name="submit"` here because you are overwritting FORM submit method, change it, e.g:

```
<input type="submit" name="bsubmit">
```

Comment: My goal was to submit via javascript in the parent. This would accomplish the same thing, but I can't get it to work either.

Comment: updated answer, should fix it. But you should check your console next time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because your iframe hasn't fully loaded yet, so you need to wait for it:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementsByName('iframe')[0].onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('f0').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That’s not how submitting to an `<iframe>` works. It completely replaces the original page.